# VNC server component for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vnc, vnc-server

I'm looking for a way to listen on a specific port as a VNC **server**, then be able to send whatever I want to the connected VNC client.

There's a lot of VNC client components, but I've not yet found a .net VNC server component.

I intend to use this to allow a client to connect directly to my windows form (and only the form, so they don't see any desktop, just my window). I realise this would normally cause input issues, but I will be forcing the clients to connect in view-only mode.

I'm very familiar with the various User32/Gdi32 platform APIs for capturing a window's contents to an image, so if it's a case of writing image data to a VNC server stream, that's fine too.

Where should I start? Is there an existing VNC server component that does what I'm describing? If not, is anyone aware of a RFB protocol component that makes it easier to communicate with a VNC client, perhaps even performing the image diff and sending only the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a component, but [Alkit VNC](http://www.alkit.se/avnc/) does seem to do what you're asking, which is share a single window using a VNC server.  The source is available, too.